# How to avoid storing white spaces in Mysql Database?

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I'm working on personal Information.jsp, in which I've to store website in database column. white spaces are stored, if user doesn't give any input. I've used `trim()` to avoid that. but It doesn't give proper output.

### Personal Action

```
String[] splits=webSites.trim().split("//");
String split1=splits[0].trim();

if(split1.equals("http:")|| split1.equals("https:")){
    vo.setWebSites(splits[1].trim());
}else{
    vo.setWebSites(webSites.trim());

}
```

### PersonalInformation.jsp

```html
<div class="width2 margin-bottom margin-top">
    <div class="profile-text">
        Website
    </div>
    <div class="profile-right">
        <s:textfield name="webSites" id="webSites"   cssClass="profile-input" cssStyle="height:30px;" title="Please enter your website" data-toggle="tooltip" maxlength="50" />
        (Example:http://www.loginhire.com)
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by _"doesn't give proper output"_? what output did you get?

Comment: Are you counting empty string "" as whitespace? Because it isn't.

Comment: yes. I'm counting empty string as white space.

Answer (score 0):

*"white spaces are stored , if user doesn't give any input."*

`how to avoid storing white spaces?`

validate user input before storing.

```
if(webSites.trim().equals("") || webSites==null)
    //prevent from storing to database or alert user
```